# Display Hierarchy Tree by CSS

Tags: html, css

How can I dynamically limit the line from Root to Folder 3?
Right now this line goes all the way to the end of tree.
Please take a look at the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JEPtg/329/)

Here is my HTML and CSS Code:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
}
ul {
  text-indent: .6em;
  border-left: 1px solid red;
}
ul ul {
  margin-top: -1.25em;
  margin-left: 1em;
}
li {
  position: relative;
  bottom: -1.25em;
}
li:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2em;
  height: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: -.75em;
  border-top: 1px solid gray;
}
ul ul:before,
h3:before,
li:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  background: salmon;
  border: 1px solid green;
  top: 1em;
  left: .4em;
}
h3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1em;
  left: 1.75em;
}
h3:before {
  left: -2.25em;
  top: .5em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>Root</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>Folder 1
      <ul>
        <li>Sub Folder 1.1
          <ul>
            <li>file1.xml</li>
            <li>file2.xml</li>
            <li>file3.xml</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>file.html</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Folder 2</li>
    <li>Folder 3
      <ul>
        <li>file1.xml</li>
        <li>file2.xml</li>
        <li>file3.xml</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Please help.  Thank you so much!